# How to get correct bounding boxes using the trained CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have trained a CNN model with a decent accuracy of close to 0.93. It has been trained using the  [The Street View House Numbers (SVHN) Dataset](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/) consisting of 10 classes for 10 numbers (0 - 9)

The dataset that I used consisted of 32x32 images which were resized to 227x227, the shape that model was designed with. To detect the bounding box, I am:

- Resizing the image to 1/4 * height, 1/4 * width
- Generating image pyramids for 4 levels
- Moving a slider and using the model for detection with input as the slider window

Here is how I did this:

```
def pyramid(image):
    pyr = [image]
    pd = image

    for i in range(4):
    pdown = cv2.pyrDown(pd)
    pd = pdown
    pyr.append(pdown)

    return pyr

window = (48,48)
stride = (4,4)

def slider():
    for row in range(0, img.shape[0], stride[1]):
        for col in range(0, img.shape[1], stride[0]):
            # yield the current window
            yield (col, row, img[row:row+window[0], col:col+window[1]])
```

The method `pyramid` generates a pyramid upto 4 levels. The method slider moves a sliding window 48x48 with 4x4 strides. Here is how I am using them to make predictions:

```
l = 1
loaded_model = keras.models.load_model("model.hdf5")
for resized in pyramid(img):
    img = resized
    i = 0
    for (x, y, win) in slider():
        i = i + 1
        if win.shape[0] != window[0] and win.shape[1] != window[1]:
            continue

        winc = np.copy(win)
        win = cv2.resize(win, (227,227))
        win = win.astype('float32') / 255.
        proba = loaded_model.predict_proba(np.expand_dims(win, axis = 0))
        _class = loaded_model.predict_classes(np.expand_dims(win, axis = 0))
        #print("Max: ", np.max(proba))
        if np.max(proba) >= 0.93:
        filename = "win/{}-{}-{}.png".format(str(l), _class[0], str(round(np.max(proba), 2)))
        cv2.imwrite(filename, winc)

    l = l + 1
    print(resized.shape)
```

I have filtered images where the detected probability of the class is above 0.93 but still it generates lots of classes. I am not sure how could I generate bounding boxes using this method. Is there a way you could suggest on how to get bounding boxes with my trained CNN?

Comment: Since the images are cropped I think in this case sliding window should work well. What you can do is adjusting the threshold, like this `if np.max(proba) >= 0.99:` . 0.93 is the validation dataset accuracy but not a good value for the prediction probability. I have tried using **Selective Search** algorithm to generate proposal bounding boxes but it does not work well on small sized images.

Comment: Hi Amanda, Is your problem resolved now. Else, If possible for you, can you please share an Output Image where you could see Lots of Classes so that we can understand the problem exactly and then we can work towards resolution of the issue. Thanks.